# How do I code a generic validation API endpoint using fluent validation?

Tags: c#, .net, validation, fluentvalidation

What I want to do is send my `validator_dto` and my model to the API endpoint and return true if it is suitable for my validation class, return false if it is not appropriate and give me a list of properties as a return if there are errors. What coding do I need to do? below is my validation class which i use without API endpoint and call style in controller. How should I act here?

```
public class ValidationTool
{
    //public static List<string> Validations(IValidator validator, object entity)
    public static List<ValidationFailure> Validations(IValidator validator, object entity)
    {
        var context = new ValidationContext<object>(entity);
        var result = validator.Validate(context);

        if (!result.IsValid)
        {
            //return result.Errors.Select(error => error.ErrorMessage).ToList();
            return result.Errors.ToList();

        }
        //return new List<string>();
        return new List<ValidationFailure>();
    }


    //aop icin
    public static void Validate(IValidator validator, object entity)
    {
        var context = new ValidationContext<object>(entity);
        var result = validator.Validate(context);
        if (!result.IsValid)
        {
            //throw new ValidationException(result.Errors);

            var validationErrors = result.Errors.Select(error => error.ErrorMessage).ToList();
            throw new ValidationException(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, validationErrors));



        }
    }

    public static async Task ValidateAsync(IValidator validator, object entity)
    {
        var context = new ValidationContext<object>(entity);
        var result = await validator.ValidateAsync(context);
        if (!result.IsValid)
        {
            throw new ValidationException(result.Errors);
        }
    }
}
```

**UI controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddNew(MemberRole_Add_Dto Model)
        {
var validationErrors = ValidationTool.Validations(new MemberRole_Add_Validator(), Model);

            if (validationErrors.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var error in validationErrors)
                {
                    //ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error);
                    ModelState.AddModelError(error.PropertyName, error.ErrorMessage);
                    string Hatalar = "";
                    foreach (var modelState in ModelState.Values)
                    {
                        foreach (var modelError in modelState.Errors)
                        {
                            Hatalar += modelError.ErrorMessage + "#";
                        }
                    }
                    MyResult.ResultText += "<br>" + Hatalar;
                }
            }
```